# Do React class components get automatically converted into functional components during the compilation process?

Tags: reactjs

Do React class components get automatically converted into functional components during the compilation process? and that's why using functional component is suggested.

I was just wondering what are the main reasons that developer of react always suggest to write functional components.

Answer (score 0):

No, both class components and functional components are supported natively by React. The reason functional components are preferred is that in the vast majority of cases they are significantly easier to write and to reason about than class components.